# question about navigationController and pvc

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, addressbook

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/*
 When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
 */
//detailViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];

ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
pvc.displayedPerson = [searchArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];

}
```

In my tableview, when a cell is clicked, the above code is executed a new view is pushed and the items (address, phone, etc) do nothing when touched.

How do I make it so that when the address is touched, Google Maps launches
If the phone number is touched,  the phonecall is placed

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm having a more basic problem than URL schemes.

How do I get the data out of the ABPersonViewController that's displayed. 

The screen displays the phone numbers, addresses, emails, etc but how do I actually retrieve that data and store it in a NSString or NSURL, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW26